# How to get 1.1 Definition of X

Tags: theorems

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[left=2.50cm, right=2.54cm, top=2.54cm, bottom=2.54cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{xpatch}%To add . to Def with swapnumber below.
\xpatchcmd\swappedhead{~}{.~}{}{}

%To import frontmatter and mainmatter to the article class
\makeatletter

\newif\if@mainmatter \@mainmattertrue

\newcommand\mainmatter{%
\cleardoublepage
\@mainmattertrue
\pagenumbering{arabic}}
\makeatother

\swapnumbers
 
\newtheorem{Definition}[equation]{{\large \normalfont\rmfamily\scshape Definition}}

\renewcommand{\theequation}{%
\thesection.%
\ifnum\value{subsection}>0 \arabic{subsection}.\fi
\arabic{equation}%
}

\theoremstyle{remark}

\begin{document}

\section{The unwanted parentheses enclosing \guillemotleft of the drift of u\guillemotright}

\begin{Definition}[of the drift of $u$]

\[\textnormal{Here is the defining sentence.}\]

\end{Definition}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't quite follow what you're asking.  Could you elaborate in text?

Comment: For your upcoming 153rd question: please read [marked as a code sample](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1192)

Comment: @Teepeemm I have problems with editing the title. It should be "How to get 1.1 Definition of X.", so there is a dot at the end. If you compile my MWE again you will see the dot after (the dot of u). So the target is to obtain 1.1 Definition of the drift of u. instead of 1.1 Definition (of the drift of u).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here I leave out all details. You don't need `\swapnumbers` nor to patch `\swappednumbers`, because you fix the formatting in the theorem style.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheoremstyle{frode}
  {}
  {}
  {\itshape}
  {}
  {}
  {.}
  {0.5em}
  {\thmnumber{#2. }\thmname{\textsc{#1}}\thmnote{ (#3)}}
\newtheoremstyle{frodenoparentheses}
  {}
  {}
  {\normalfont}
  {}
  {}
  {.}
  {0.5em}
  {\thmnumber{#2. }\thmname{\textsc{#1}}\thmnote{ #3}}

\theoremstyle{frode}
\newtheorem{Theorem}[equation]{Theorem}
\theoremstyle{frodenoparentheses}
\newtheorem{Definition}[equation]{Definition}

\begin{document}

\section{Test}

\begin{Theorem}
This is a theorem.
\end{Theorem}

\begin{Theorem}[Somebody]
This is a theorem with a note.
\end{Theorem}

\begin{Definition}
This is a definition.
\end{Definition}

\begin{Definition}[of the drift of $u$]
This is a definition with a note.
\end{Definition}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Adjust to suit your test. But, please, don't use `\large`.

Comment: Many thanks! I discovered that with \theoremstyle{frode}
\newtheorem{Definition}[equation]{Definition}
\theoremstyle{frodenoparentheses}
\newtheorem{Def}[equation]{Definition} facilitates switching between the two styles! :)

Answer (score 1):

Is using `amsthm` an absolute necessity? If not you can simply redefine the theorem building macros from `latex.ltx`.

(I also removed a bunch of unnecessary stuff from the MWE.)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


\makeatletter

\def\@begintheorem#1#2{\trivlist
   \item[\hskip \labelsep{\bfseries #2\ #1}]\itshape}
\def\@opargbegintheorem#1#2#3{\trivlist
      \item[\hskip \labelsep{\bfseries #2\ #1\ #3}]\itshape}

\makeatother

 
\newtheorem{Definition}[equation]{Definition}

\renewcommand{\theequation}{%
\thesection.%
\ifnum\value{subsection}>0 \arabic{subsection}.\fi
\arabic{equation}%
}


\begin{document}

\section{No unwanted parentheses}

\begin{Definition}[of the drift of $u$]

\[\textnormal{Here is the defining sentence.}\]

\end{Definition}

\end{document}
```

---

If you wish to use `amsthm`, this is explained on page 10 of the package manual. You need to create a new theorem style (following is quoted from said manual).

```
\newtheoremstyle{noparens}%
{}{}%
{\itshape}{}%
{\bfseries}{.}%
{ }%
{\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}\thmnote{ #3}}
```

and use it for your theorems; you need to adjust appropriately the font commands for the formatting of theorem head to your specific case.

Comment: Thanks. "Is using amsthm an absolute necessity?" Yes, there are  m a n y  other theorem like environments in the document which ought to have the parentheses.

Comment: I have problems with editing the title. It should be "How to get 1.1 Definition of X.", so there is a dot at the end. If you compile my MWE again you will see the dot after (the dot of u). So the target is to obtain 1.1 Definition of the drift of u. instead of 1.1 Definition (of the drift of u).