How to insert Unicodes in Overleaf, as in TexStudio?
In TexStudio I just click Edit => Insert Unicode Character to get 0x...., and after filling in with 03D8 to get 0x03D8, and compiling, I obtain archaic Greek Koppa. Similarly, 0x2289 gives me the symbol for not being a superset. How may I go about to insert Unicodes similarly in Overleaf? Lualatex is used, so the compilation ought to succeed as soon as the unicode is entered properly.
Edit - an mwe which does not compile:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}


0x03D8

0x2289


\end{document}


Please add which operating system you use. Different OS have different input methods for unicode chars. Maybe also add which browser you use.

When you write 'Overleaf', do you actually mean 'LaTeX'? Please advise.

@Mico  I meant the Overleaf Tex-editor. If there is a canonical way to represent Koppa in Latex via Unicode, it should work in the Overleaf editor, I gather, and I tried Texstudio's  0x03D8, as well as Ux03D8, in Overleaf to no avail.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I use macOS Sonoma 14.4.1.

https://ladedu.com/how-to-enter-unicode-characters-on-a-mac/

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thanks, I inserted and see the symbols in the tex-file - but, unfortunately, they do not compile.

"do not compile" isn't a useful error descriptions. We can't see your tex file. We don;t know which compiler you selected in overleaf and we don't know if your font has these characters.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I compile with lualatex.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz May it be that I have to add more fonts? ...

Please add a MWE and your .log file.

there is a difference in editor input between overleaf and texstudio but neither has any influence over how latex processes the characters

how can we know if you need more fonts? If the document works on one system and fails on another then you will have messages in the log saying what is wrong, but if you show no input or output or log messages it's impossible to help

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz $\nsupseteq$  gives the symbol for not being a superset which is promised by Unicode 0x2289, so it is presumably not a lack of fonts in that case.

@FrodeAlfsonBjørdal It is rather pointless to engage in long chat conversations if you refuse to give us the information needed to solve the problem.

by default lualatex does not use unicode fonts for math so your last example is unrelated to your question

@DavidCarlisle  I added an mwe.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I added an mwe.

where? also show the log you get, so we don't have to guess what is wrong.

don't use T1 encoding with luatex,  But that applies equally to texstudio. an mwe should be a document that works in your local tex installation and fails in overleaf, an exampel that failsd everywhere isn't an example of your question

@FrodeAlfsonBjørdal ... you are not inputting the characters as unicode. Your example compiles as expected and produces the numbers instead of symbols. If you want to use unicode characters, use Ϙ or whatever in your code. The link above tells you how to write them on a mac.

why do you say the unicode has been entered? you just have ascii text in the example (and classic 8 bit fonts, not luatex's normal unicode fonts)

what do you mean by "does not compile"  I get no error from the posted document if used with lualatex.

I guess writing the comment https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/712942/how-to-get-1-1-definition-of-x#comment1771953_712942 was a complete waste of my time

The example seems completely unrelated to the question in the title as the posted document would work the same way in any tex system so it would not act differently in texstudio and overleaf, however....
You could do
\documentclass{article}
% No!!! don't use 8-bit fonts with unicode engines \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}


0x03D8 [^^^^03d8] or [Ϙ] or [\symbol{"03D8}]

0x2289 [^^^^2289] or [⊉] or [\symbol{"2289}]


\end{document}

which produces the log
Missing character: There is no Ϙ (U+03D8) in font [lmroman10-regular]:+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no Ϙ (U+03D8) in font [lmroman10-regular]:+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no Ϙ (U+03D8) in font [lmroman10-regular]:+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no ⊉ (U+2289) in font [lmroman10-regular]:+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no ⊉ (U+2289) in font [lmroman10-regular]:+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no ⊉ (U+2289) in font [lmroman10-regular]:+tlig;!

As Latin Modern doesn't have Math or Greek.
However choosing suitable fonts...

\documentclass{article}
% No!!! don't use 8-bit fonts with unicode engines \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}

\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}


0x03D8 [^^^^03d8] or [Ϙ] or [\symbol{"03D8}]

0x2289 $[^^^^2289]$ or $[⊉]$ or $[\symbol{"2289}]$


\end{document}


Many thanks! ^^^^03d8, \symbol{"03D8} are different from 0x03D8 which I discovered worked in TexStudio, and your answer is not unrelated to the question in the title - as the former codes work in Overleaf, but the latter does not.

@FrodeAlfsonBjørdal No. Writing  0x03D8  as text in any editor will just write  0x03D8  into the output, Open your "mwe" in texstudio and process it you will just get  0x03D8 . There will be no difference in behaviour whichever editor you use. Please next time provide an exampe and if getting an error provide the error message from the log. As you describe in your question you do not enter  0x03D8  into the document you opened a separate menu in the editor and entered a control code. That is obviously editor specific but unrelated to typing  0x03D8  as text

"you do not enter 0x03D8 into the document you opened a separate menu in the editor and entered a control code. That is obviously editor specific but unrelated to typing 0x03D8 as text" That is clearly right. But TexStudio did not give me any clues as to what code I would need in Overleaf, and I did not find anything which could help me by looking for information for several hours.

you could simply have copied the text you had written in texstudio which would have worked just as the text here was written in emacs (and I used ctrx-8 x  03D8 to type Ϙ) but you can copy it here or to texstudio or to overleaf. Your question implies the document that you posted produced  a Ϙ if typeset from texstudio, which is simply not the case.
